# NPM environment variables not working in windows?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, windows, npm

In my package.json file I'm trying to compile less code using versioning, something like this:

```
"scripts" {
...
"build:css": "lessc --source-map css/index.less build/$npm_package_name.$npm_package_version.css",
...
}
```

The problem is that the output files come back as

```
$npm_package_name.$npm_package_version.css
```

instead of

```
my-project.1.0.0.css
```

I've read that you can do

```
%npm_package_name%.%npm_package_version%.css
```

but this hasn't worked for me.

Anyone know why the variables aren't working? Do these variables work at all in Windows? If so, how do I make them work?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why aren't the variables working / do the variables work in Windows / how do I make them work? Updated in the question

Comment: I think it would be best for you to use `gulp` and get env variables with `process.env` rather than having OS dependent scripts on your `package.json`

Comment: Yes, normally what I do is use Grunt, but for this project I specifically need to use npm. If there is a solution to this problem that would be great.

Comment: How did you set those variables? Using the percent syntax is what Windows needs in most cases.

Comment: Well I didn't set them. My understanding is that the node environment sets them.

Comment: The %variable% format is the right one **if** you are using cmd.exe as your shell.   What happens when you use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package.json works for me on Windows 10:

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "Unlicense"
}
```

Note however that the environment variable substitution occurs after its been echoed by NPM, so the output looks like this:

```
C:\try\x>npm test

> x@1.0.0 test C:\try\x
> echo %npm_package_name%.%npm_package_version%.css

x.1.0.0.css
```

Comment: Ah yes, very helpful. The problem was that I was using the git bash (unix-based) and not cmd.exe. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To make it cross-platform, use [`cross-var`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var):

`"scripts" {
...
"build:css": "cross-var lessc --source-map css/index.less build/$npm_package_name.$npm_package_version.css",
...
}`